Relative merits of more specific Azure DevOps pipeline task and more general one
Is there any reason why this:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Apply EF database migrations
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: ef
      arguments: 'database update --project .\MyProject'

is better or worse than
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Apply EF database migrations
    inputs:
      script: |
        dotnet ef database update --project .\My.Project

They both work and appear to do the same thing. The advantage I see to the latter is that it directly uses the command I run locally to apply migrations that I've generated to the development database on my local machine, without having to break that command into pieces.

Generally, they achieve the same results. For their differences, you may consider the following:
For DotNetCoreCLI@2 Task

This task is specifically designed for .NET Core CLI commands, making it more intuitive and easier to use for .NET-related operations. And it can provide more detailed logging and error specific to .NET commands.
In some rare cases, using this task may cause some problems or the actual results may not meet your expectations. For example, NU1100: Unable to resolve Azure DevOps nuget package and Failing unit tests result in obscure error message on CI build / pull request when using DotNetCoreCLI.

For CmdLine@2 Task

You can run any command as you would in a local terminal. If you already have a script that works locally, you can reuse it without modification, making it simpler and quicker to set up.

This task is more generic and might not provide the detailed logging for .NET-specific commands compared to DotNetCoreCLI@2 Task.


You can choose a task based on your actual needs and scenarios.

Thanks, the detailed logging seems a bonus.

TL;DR it probably doesn't make much difference to use one task or another for very simple and custom dotnet commands such as dotnet ef database update --project .\My.Project.
Personally I'd use DotNetCoreCLI@2 to run all dotnet commands on the pipeline, for the sake of consistency.
Some notes regarding DotNetCoreCLI@2
The .NET Core v2 task task was created to make it easier and convenient to run .NET CLI commands and related tasks as part of an Azure pipeline.
For example, consider the following task:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*UnitTests.csproj'

Property projects supports wildcards, which helps us filter a subset of the projects (in this case, the unit test projects). After the tests run, the test results and code coverage will be automatically published to Azure DevOps.
Also, and generally speaking, the more complex the dotnet command you want to run is, the more convenient it is to use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task - it's easier to configure one if its many properties, as opposed to remembering all the flags and its values.
Supported properties:
# .NET Core v2
# Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build' # 'build' | 'push' | 'pack' | 'publish' | 'restore' | 'run' | 'test' | 'custom'. Required. Command. Default: build.
    #publishWebProjects: true # boolean. Optional. Use when command = publish. Publish web projects. Default: true.
    #projects: # string. Optional. Use when command = build || command = restore || command = run || command = test || command = custom || publishWebProjects = false. Path to project(s) or solution(s). 
    #custom: # string. Required when command = custom. Custom command. 
    #arguments: # string. Optional. Use when command = build || command = publish || command = run || command = test || command = custom. Arguments. 
    #restoreArguments: # string. Optional. Use when command = restore. Arguments. 
    #publishTestResults: true # boolean. Optional. Use when command = test. Publish test results and code coverage. Default: true.
    #testRunTitle: # string. Optional. Use when command = test. Test run title. 
    #zipAfterPublish: true # boolean. Optional. Use when command = publish. Zip published projects. Default: true.
    #modifyOutputPath: true # boolean. Optional. Use when command = publish. Add project's folder name to publish path. Default: true.
    #packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg' # string. Alias: searchPatternPush. Required when command = push. Path to NuGet package(s) to publish. Default: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg.
    #nuGetFeedType: 'internal' # 'internal' | 'external'. Required when command = push. Target feed location. Default: internal.
    #publishVstsFeed: # string. Alias: feedPublish. Required when command = push && nuGetFeedType = internal. Target feed. 
    #publishFeedCredentials: # string. Alias: externalEndpoint. Required when command = push && nuGetFeedType = external. NuGet server. 
    #packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj' # string. Alias: searchPatternPack. Required when command = pack. Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack. Default: **/*.csproj.
    #configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)' # string. Alias: configurationToPack. Optional. Use when command = pack. Configuration to Package. Default: $(BuildConfiguration).
    #packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' # string. Alias: outputDir. Optional. Use when command = pack. Package Folder. Default: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).
    #nobuild: false # boolean. Optional. Use when command = pack. Do not build. Default: false.
    #includesymbols: false # boolean. Optional. Use when command = pack. Include Symbols. Default: false.
    #includesource: false # boolean. Optional. Use when command = pack. Include Source. Default: false.
  # Feeds and authentication
    #feedsToUse: 'select' # 'select' | 'config'. Alias: selectOrConfig. Required when command = restore. Feeds to use. Default: select.
    #vstsFeed: # string. Alias: feedRestore. Optional. Use when selectOrConfig = select && command = restore. Use packages from this Azure Artifacts feed. 
    #includeNuGetOrg: true # boolean. Optional. Use when selectOrConfig = select && command = restore. Use packages from NuGet.org. Default: true.
    #nugetConfigPath: # string. Optional. Use when selectOrConfig = config && command = restore. Path to NuGet.config. 
    #externalFeedCredentials: # string. Alias: externalEndpoints. Optional. Use when selectOrConfig = config && command = restore. Credentials for feeds outside this organization/collection. 
  # Advanced
    #noCache: false # boolean. Optional. Use when command = restore. Disable local cache. Default: false.
    #restoreDirectory: # string. Alias: packagesDirectory. Optional. Use when command = restore. Destination directory. 
    #verbosityRestore: 'Normal' # '-' | 'Quiet' | 'Minimal' | 'Normal' | 'Detailed' | 'Diagnostic'. Optional. Use when command = restore. Verbosity. Default: Normal.
  # Advanced
    #publishPackageMetadata: true # boolean. Optional. Use when command = push && nuGetFeedType = internal && command = push. Publish pipeline metadata. Default: true.
  # Pack options
    #versioningScheme: 'off' # 'off' | 'byPrereleaseNumber' | 'byEnvVar' | 'byBuildNumber'. Required when command = pack. Automatic package versioning. Default: off.
    #versionEnvVar: # string. Required when versioningScheme = byEnvVar && command = pack. Environment variable. 
    #majorVersion: '1' # string. Alias: requestedMajorVersion. Required when versioningScheme = byPrereleaseNumber && command = pack. Major. Default: 1.
    #minorVersion: '0' # string. Alias: requestedMinorVersion. Required when versioningScheme = byPrereleaseNumber && command = pack. Minor. Default: 0.
    #patchVersion: '0' # string. Alias: requestedPatchVersion. Required when versioningScheme = byPrereleaseNumber && command = pack. Patch. Default: 0.
  # Advanced
    #buildProperties: # string. Optional. Use when command = pack. Additional build properties. 
    #verbosityPack: 'Normal' # '-' | 'Quiet' | 'Minimal' | 'Normal' | 'Detailed' | 'Diagnostic'. Optional. Use when command = pack. Verbosity. Default: Normal.
  # Advanced
    #workingDirectory: # string. Optional. Use when command != restore && command != push && command != pack && command != pack && command != push && command != restore. Working directory.

